# deployment failed because of permision [Passenger+nginx]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, passenger

I am new in deployment world i tried to deploy my rails application on amzone ES2

I made some changes in nginx.conf file which require for finding ruby path and its working fine and i am able to restart nginx also

but when i try to access webpage via IP its throw and error like below image

[image]

and below are the log of server

```
App 4334 stdout: 
[ 2017-03-12 02:08:02.1355 2511/7f805c0c8700 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/deploy/sample_app: An error occurred while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: 987308d1
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-qds73G.html
  Message from application: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini (Errno::EACCES)
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger.rb:282:in `initialize'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger.rb:282:in `open'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger.rb:282:in `parse_ini_file'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger.rb:99:in `locate_directories'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:75:in `init_passenger'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:155:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'


[ 2017-03-12 02:08:02.1385 2511/7f805d55c700 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:285 ]: [Client 1-4] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 987308d1. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

do i need to modify permission for `/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini`

I modify permission for above file now i have below error

```
App 5491 stdout: 
App 5491 stderr:  [passenger_native_support.so] trying to compile for the current user (deploy) and Ruby interpreter...
App 5491 stderr:      (set PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
App 5491 stderr: Unable to autodetect the currently active RVM gem set name. This could happen if you ran this program using 'sudo' instead of 'rvmsudo'. When using RVM, you're always supposed to use 'rvmsudo' instead of 'sudo!'.
App 5491 stderr: 
App 5491 stderr: Please try rerunning this program using 'rvmsudo'. If that doesn't help, please contact this program's author for support.
[ 2017-03-12 02:38:31.4982 5425/7f203e5c7700 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/deploy/sample_app: An error occurred while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: c80d4a5e
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-YnUzbb.html
  Message from application: exit (SystemExit)
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/platform_info/ruby.rb:311:in `exit'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/platform_info/ruby.rb:311:in `rvm_ruby_string'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/platform_info.rb:98:in `rvm_ruby_string'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/platform_info/ruby.rb:69:in `ruby_command'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/platform_info.rb:98:in `ruby_command'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:337:in `block (3 levels) in compile'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:335:in `chdir'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:335:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils/tmpio.rb:70:in `mktmpdir'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:334:in `block in compile'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:378:in `block (2 levels) in try_directories'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:377:in `chdir'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:377:in `block in try_directories'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:371:in `each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:371:in `each_with_index'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:371:in `try_directories'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:329:in `compile'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:219:in `compile_and_load'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:52:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb:439:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @jackRothrock tell me what issue you have?

Comment: rvmsudo, capistrano builds with the correct ruby version, and the passenger.conf is pointed to the exact same ruby version as well

Comment: did you restart `nginx`

Comment: yeah I restarted it

Comment: I think I may have found it. `sudo passenger-config validate-install` says I have a conflict - passenger being installed for the systems ruby, as well as the rvm's ruby. I deleted the folder for the system as well as switched rubies and uninstalled it, but it still says it. Can't track down where I have it linked. I greped down the nginx path and it showed up blank. Any thoughts?

Comment: are you able to run ruby correctly on server and nginx service running properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157049/discussion-between-uzaif-and-jack-rothrock).